# lexical and preprocessor issues ios on project rename

Tags: ios, xcode, preprocessor, lexical

i've changed the name of my project schema. Project was running successfully before but now it gives lexical and preprocessor issue . I've carefully checked buildphase and buildsetting headerpaths. Error is coming in cocos2d sub folder linking .I ve been stuck in this problem and trying to solve it from morning, i ve some lazy options as well to solve this issue, but i want to know what exactly wrong? Any help will be highly appreciated
Here is the snap shot of error

[image: following error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the issue. when i changed the name of project name it also changed the **prefix of header path** that is before the name of project was **xyz** which i changed to **mdot.** **"$(project_name)/libs/cocos2dx"** before this was interpreting as  "xyz/libs/cocos2dx" and when changed the name of project it was interpreting as **"mdot/libs/cocos2dx"** bec the folder name of the project was still **xyz** i forcefully changed the string to **"xyz/libs/cocos2dx"** from **"$(projectname/libs/cocos2dx)"** actually solve the problem and now compiler was pretty clear where the header files are.I hope it cld help other as well

Comment: You should check this answer. It worked for me :). Lesson of the day: Don't rely on Xcode to rename your project. Do it by hand if you receive errors.

Comment: you read and understand my answer. you should be aware of settings of your project that's y i was keen to solve the issue which i did soo any ways thanks